How to Maintain Rounded Corners with Full Background Color in Flutter Sidebar?
Question:
I'm working on a Flutter Windows app and trying to achieve a sidebar design with rounded corners and a full background color. However, I'm having trouble maintaining the rounded corners when using AnimatedContainer for the sidebar background color.
Here's what I want to achieve:

But my current implementation looks like this:

The issue is that while the AnimatedContainer provides the full color, it disrupts the rounded corner effect.
Here is the code I have so far:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool _isHovered = false;
  int _selectedSidebarIndex = 0;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void _setHovered(bool isHovered) {
    setState(() {
      _isHovered = isHovered;
    });
  }

  void _onSidebarItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedSidebarIndex = index;
    });
    if (ResponsiveUtil.isMobile(context) ||
        ResponsiveUtil.isMobileLarge(context)) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }

  Widget _buildSidebarItem(String assetPath, String title, int index) {
    final bool isSelected = index == _selectedSidebarIndex;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _onSidebarItemTapped(index),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: getBorderRadius(_selectedSidebarIndex, index),
          color: isSelected ? AppColors.kWhiteColor : AppColors.sideBarMenuColor,
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(width: 20.0),
            SvgPicture.asset(
              assetPath,
              width: 20.0,
              height: 20.0,
              color: AppColors.kSideMenuIconColor,
            ),
            if (_isHovered || isSelected) ...[
              const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  title,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: isSelected ? AppColors.kBlueColor : Colors.white,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return const ApplicantMainScreen();
      case 1:
        return AnimatedSideBarContent.buildDBSFormSideBarWidgetContent();
      case 2:
        return AnimatedSideBarContent.buildReferenceCheckSideBarWidgetContent();
      case 3:
        return AnimatedSideBarContent.buildSMCSideBarContent();
      case 4:
        return AnimatedSideBarContent.buildIDSideBarWidgetContent();
      case 5:
        return AnimatedSideBarContent.buildRightToWorkSideBarWidgetContent();
      case 6:
        return AnimatedSideBarContent.buildAdverseCreditCheckSideBarWidgetContent();
      default:
        return const ApplicantMainScreen();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool isMobile = ResponsiveUtil.isMobile(context) ||
        ResponsiveUtil.isMobileLarge(context);

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        isAdminActive: false,
        isMobile: isMobile,
        scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey,
      ),
      drawer: isMobile
          ? Drawer(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.dashboardIcon, 'Dashboard', 0),
                  _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.dbsCheckIcon, 'DBS Form', 1),
                  _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.refCheckIcon, 'Reference Check', 2),
                  _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.smcIcon, 'SMC', 3),
                  _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.rightToWorkIcon, 'Right to work', 4),
                  _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.creditCheckIcon, 'Credit Check', 5),
                  _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.idCheckIcon, 'ID', 6),
                ],
              ),
            )
          : null,
      body: Row(
        children: [
          if (!isMobile)
            MouseRegion(
              onEnter: (_) => _setHovered(true),
              onExit: (_) => _setHovered(false),
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                width: _isHovered ? 200.0 : 60.0,
                color: AppColors.sideBarMenuColor,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.dashboardIcon, 'Dashboard', 0),
                    _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.dbsCheckIcon, 'DBS Form', 1),
                    _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.refCheckIcon, 'Reference Check', 2),
                    _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.smcIcon, 'SMC', 3),
                    _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.rightToWorkIcon, 'Right to work', 4),
                    _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.creditCheckIcon, 'Credit Check', 5),
                    _buildSidebarItem(SideBarMenuIcons.idCheckIcon, 'ID', 6),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: _buildContent(_selectedSidebarIndex),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

BorderRadius getBorderRadius(
  int selected,
  int currentButton,
) {
  if (selected == currentButton) {
    return const BorderRadius.only(
      topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
    );
  }
  if (selected == currentButton - 1) {
    return const BorderRadius.only(
      topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
    );
  }
  if (selected == currentButton + 1) {
    return const BorderRadius.only(
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
    );
  }
  return BorderRadius.zero;
}

How can I achieve the desired design with rounded corners and a full background color for the sidebar?
Any help would be appreciated!

